# phrabricator : Show custom tag created in maniphest within a card for workboard

Tags: php, phabricator, wikimedia

I have created custom fields in maniphest, I want to show that custom field in workboard.

I could see that wikimedia has done this for their use ref slide no : 7 (Design, wikidata) in the following ppt and the url mentioned below :

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/12/Introduction-to-Phabricator-WikiCon-2016.pdf

https://secure.phabricator.com/project/board/1268/[Phabricator Site where this is in place](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lK7p2.png)

Is there a way to do it ?[Another place where this is implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Um0k.png)

Answer (score 0):

These are not [custom fields](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/custom_fields/) but [projects](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/projects/). A common use-case for projects is to operate as tags. For example, on your first image, the Phabricator instance have a “[Feature-Request](https://secure.phabricator.com/project/view/1403/)” project/tag.

When you assign a project to a task, it is displayed on the card on a workboard.

Displaying custom fields on the cards on a workboard is not currently possible. This is tracked at [T4863](https://secure.phabricator.com/T4863).